# How do I connect to 2 mySQL tables in the same asp page?

Tags: mysql, database, asp-classic

I have an ASP classic page that retrieves mySQL records just fine. I want to use this first of the page as the header record. then, another table has detail info in many records, and I want to display that below. Like a part number, and then display the orders of that parts:
Vineyard: Name, location, phone, website
  Wines: Types, Varietals, Flavors, Price

I have one pages the returns the Part Number info, and another page that returns the Details info, but when I combine the two data class on the same page, it breaks. Ironically, I'm moving to mySQL, but the current pages are using Frontpage ASP programming, and it works great with an Access database.

Here's the code in the top half of the page:

```
<% 
'declare the variables 
Dim Connection
Dim ConnectionString
Dim Recordset
Dim SQL
Dim rsVineyard


'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
SQL = "SELECT * FROM Vineyards WHERE ID =" & Server.HtmlEncode(Request("V"))

'define the connection string, specify database driver
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=hosted.com; DATABASE=WineDB; UID=WineDB; PASSWORD=WinePasword; OPTION=3"

'create an instance of the ADO connection and Recordset objects
Set Connection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsVineyard = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

'Open the connection to the database
Connection.Open ConnString

'Open the Recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
rsVineyard.Open SQL,Connection

%>

<% 

'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If rsVineyard.EOF Then 
Response.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
Do While NOT rsVineyard.Eof   
%>
```

Then this is the Wines code in the bottom half of the page:

```
<% 
'declare the variables 
Dim wConnection
Dim wConnString
Dim rsWines
Dim wSQL

'declare the SQL statement that will query the database
wSQL = "SELECT * FROM Wines WHERE Winery_Number = 21 Order By Type DESC, Name ASC, Vintage ASC"

'define the connection string, specify database driver
ConnString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=hosted.com; DATABASE=WineDB; UID=WineDB; PASSWORD=WinePasword; OPTION=3"

'create an instance of the ADO connection and Recordset objects
Set wConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsWines = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Open the connection to the database
wConnection.Open wConnString

'Open the Recordset object executing the SQL statement and return records 
rsWines.Open wSQL,wConnection

'first of all determine whether there are any records 
If rsWines.EOF Then 
    rsWines.Write("No records returned.") 
Else 
'if there are records then loop through the fields 
    Do While NOT rsWines.Eof 
%>
```

And again, they work fine on their own, but when I combine the code in one page, it errors. And I even tried using an include statement to pull the second page in, but same error.

Comment: Is the error message a secret?

Comment: Sidenote: do not concatenate SQL queries, but use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: does "end if" specially ommited?

Comment: To answer the questions: 1. @Shadow There is no error message. The page just errors and I get a error page form the host.

Comment: 2. @Dries VB Don't understand Don Not Concatenate SQL queries..." statement, I'm not that advanced. If you could upload example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: 3. @DimaSUN  End if omitted on purpose for the post.

Comment: @ChrisFreeman You're using the concatenate operator (&) to concatenate your query, which is bad practice. Read about it (with examples) [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-Parameterized-queries-to-prevent-SQL-Injection-Attacks-in-SQL-Server.aspx)

Comment: What does it mean that the page errors?

Comment: @Dreis, oh, now I get it, You mean the  "...WHERE ID =" & Server..."  OK, I'll try Khan's plan then.

Comment: @Shadow my host is GoDaddy, and when the page fails... oh duh, right there in front of me. Its a 500 (Internal Server) Error,

Comment: @ChrisFreeman you are going to need to enable detailed error messages which will greatly help you debug problems as they will tell you what the error is and which line number it pertains to. For Godaddy see https://au.godaddy.com/help/get-detailed-errors-windows-3430.

Comment: @john, the only error message i get is a 500 (Internal Server) Error. nothing else. I can try to put some error monitoring on it. Do you have a snipet that can do that?

Comment: Was the godaddy link in my last comment no good for enabling detailed errors?

Comment: @John, OK I tried the Web.config file and found that the mySQL database is not there, only one of my other Access databases. working with GoDaddy to see how we can get that connected to tracking the errors.

Comment: You don't need your database connection string in web.config for classic asp. Just need the config to enable detailed error messages in there so you can debug errors.

Comment: @John, well, as again, I'm new to al  of this, here's the info I'm working with:

Comment: @John, well, as again, I'm new to al  of this, here's the info I'm working with: The current web.config has only one Access database listed under <system.web> Plus, that <system.web> seems to be the IIS6 syntax. My admin panel says I'm IIS7. GoDad has a statement of <configuration>    <system.webServer>        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />      but nothing else, like the connection string setup. And since the connection string from the IIS6 is more complex than the base DB conn string, I feel there is a lot of info I don't have to completed the proper syntax.

Comment: Classic ASP doesn't use connection string in web.config, only ASP.NET. That last Godaddy link I sent might be no good for Classic ASP, but there's a few suggestions in this one (https://forums.iis.net/t/1156946.aspx?GoDaddy+II7+classic+asp+error+details+not+shown) including making sure your browser is set to display detailed messages too.